# MySQL Semicolon placement in Procedure

Tags: mysql, variables, syntax, phpmyadmin, procedure

I've been working on some code for a while but am having some issues. I have two identical tables - History and Checked_Out_Media - and I'm trying to take a specified record in Checked_Out_Media and move it to the History table. The primary keys are not auto-incremented so I have to make a variable for the max History table ID and increment it by one.

I think I have the code mostly correct, possibly some semi-colon placements are needed? Can you take a look?

```
Create Procedure spMoveToHistory( IN UserID char(6), IN MediaBarcode varchar(50) )

BEGIN

    SELECT @NextRow := (MAX(History_TUID) + 1)
    From History

    Insert into History
    Values (@NextRow, COM.User_ID, COM.Media_Barcode, COM.Checked_Out_Date, COM.Return_Date)
    From Checked_Out_Media as COM
    Where COM.User_ID = UserID 
         AND (COM.Media_Barcode = MediaBarcode)

END
```

Also, I'm using PHPMyAdmin which allows me to set the delimiter to `//` outside of the code.

Comment: Your SELECT and INSERT statements needs a semicolon at the end. See MySQL Docs for the CREATE PROCEDURE statement.

Comment: @miken32 I really appreciate the advice. I shall take a look. I've been doing quite a bit of programming in SQL Server and I'm trying to get a handle on MySQL - it's tearing me up inside.

Answer (score 0):

You should name the parameters so they can be distinguished from column names.  In addition, you want `insert . . . select`:

```
Create Procedure spMoveToHistory (
    IN in_UserID char(6),
    IN in_MediaBarcode varchar(50)
)
BEGIN
    SELECT @NextRow := (MAX(History_TUID) + 1)
    From History;

    Insert into History
        Select @NextRow, COM.User_ID, COM.Media_Barcode, COM.Checked_Out_Date, COM.Return_Date
        From Checked_Out_Media COM
        Where COM.User_ID = in_UserID  AND COM.Media_Barcode = in_MediaBarcode;
END;
```

Comment: Can I also add in a delete statement to delete the row in the Checked_Out_Media table? Is it possible to do another operation within the same  Procedure? It was a simple add in SQL Server, can't get that to work either.

Comment: @Gordon_Linoff The above code doesn't seem to work. There is an error after creation. The code creates the procedure then doesn't do anything when called, and shows a red underline underneath END. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final code I was able to get to work. For some reason the code Gordon offered did... nothing. It didn't insert or delete. I'm sure there was a good reason for that. I did, however rewrite my code to work:

```
Create Procedure spMoveToHistory( IN in_UserID char(6), IN in_MediaBarcode char(3) )

BEGIN

    SELECT @NextRow := (MAX(History_TUID) + 1)
           From History;

    SELECT @COM_UserID := (User_ID), 
           @COM_MediaBarcode := (Media_Barcode), 
           @COM_COD := (Check_Out_Date), 
           @COM_RD := (Return_Date)
           From Checked_Out_Media 
           Where User_ID = in_UserID  AND Media_Barcode = in_MediaBarcode;

    INSERT Into history
           VALUES(@NextRow, @COM_UserID, @COM_MediaBarcode, @COM_COD, @COM_RD);

    DELETE From checked_out_media
           Where User_ID = in_UserID  AND Media_Barcode = in_MediaBarcode;

END
```